# Возможно ли будет взломать пароль с динамической солью которая нигде не храниться?

Tags: веб-программирование, шифрование, криптография, хеширование

Допустим на клиенте вместе с паролем просить пользователя ввести слово (не менее 6 символов,оно и будет солью которую знает только пользователь,больше она нигде не фигурирует ) и дальше все делать по такой схеме

**hash(password+hash(слово))**  и отправлять этот хэш на сервер

по прибытию данных на сервер делать так

**hash(пришедший хэш + соль из БД для этого пользователя)** и сверять это с тем что лежит в БД

Comment: Зачем просить у пользователя два пароля? Ах да, это же соль, а не второй пароль. На каждую авторизацию придется запрашивать пароль и соль (два пароля). Никакой дополнительной безопасности это не принесет.

Comment: Ладно тогда просто пойдем от обратного попробуейте вломать такой пароль методом брутфорса?Ну как получилось?

Comment: Что значит взломать? Брутфорс может взломать все что угодно, вопрос времени. Зачем что-то просить вводить дополнительно, можно например половину пароля использовать как динамическую соль. [Соль](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F) нужна для того, чтобы даже получив доступ к базе усложнить перебор паролей.

Comment: Попробуйте ввести в поле ввода единственного пароля "парольсоль" - думаете это легче брутфорсить, чем "пароль" и "соль" в разных полях ввода?

Comment: Я к тому, что "взломать" довольно размытое понятие

Comment: А если пароль посолен а соль неизвестна,у вас получиться его методом брутфорса взломать(ну разумееться если брать размуные периоды времени,а не года)?

Comment: Пароли, соли, хэши делают не для защиты от брутфорса. От него всё это не поможет. Хэш пароля хранится для того, чтобы если злоумышленник получит доступ к базе данных - он не смог получить пароли пользователей. Существуют радужные таблицы для всех "легких" входных данных для всех алгоритмов хэширования. Для этого и нужна соль- чтобы невозможно было применить радужные таблицы с заранее вычисленными хэшами, даже если пароль будет `password` - никто не будет составлять радужные таблицы для `password12FHhj^&*sfитп`

Comment: Если неизвестна соль, то неизвестен и пароль. Известна соль (перехвачен запрос авторизации) - известен и пароль.

Comment: Соль где храниться?В БД а если я получу доступ к БД значит и буду знать и соль,а там уже можно взломать пароль с помощью радужной таблицы.А если я не буду знать соль то то придеться угадывать не только пароль но и соль т.е количетсво вариантов будет =количество вариантов пароля*количество вариантов соли

Comment: Если будет перехвачен запрос авторизации то тут уже ничто не поможет это раз,а во вторых соль передаеться уже в хэше(соль +пароль) т.е узнать её нельзя

Comment: `$salt = hash( str_repeat( $password, 1000 ) );` получите пароль от пользователя. Повторите его тысячу раз, найдите хэш- теперь у Вас есть шикарная соль. которая не хранится на сервере. Теперь можно не терроризировать пользователей двумя паролями.

Comment: Я не знаю больше, что Вам сказать.

Comment: Не так понял коментарий)Эту соль можно легко узнать просто повторяя то-же самое

Comment: Ее нельзя узнать не зная пароль, потому что она сделана на основе пароля. Пусть злоумышленник любым способом получил "пароль", который ввел пользователь. Точно таким же образом он получит и "соль", которую ввел пользователь, поэтому удобнее сделать соль на основе введенного пароля, а не запрашивать ее у пользователя. Пароль и соль минимум 6 символов требуете? Потребуйте 12 символов пароля и разделите его пополам. Пользователю будет удобнее всё ввести в одно поле ввода, а Вы получите и "пароль" и "соль".

Comment: Вот именно!А соль которую предлагаю я,нельзя будет узнать зная пароль,да и вообще никак (кроме перебора или по словарю но это будет очень долгим вариантом).Пароль из 2 символов тоже подходит, представьте взять этот пароль из 12 символом разделить на 2 слова,допустим фотоап (пароль) и аратата (соль) и зашифровать по такой схеме hash(пароль + hash (соль)) и отаслать на сервер а там дальше все стандартно.Ну лучше использовать 2 не связанных слова.Теперь представьте сколько будет нужно вариантов перебрать для взлома это пароля?

Comment: Делайте :) Но сначала еще раз прочитайте сообщение, где я писал про то, что соль не может помочь от брутфорса.

Comment: @Icsdssd, в некоторых случаях соль вообще не нужна :) Вот функция http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php в php - при каждой генерации хэша от одного и того же пароля, хэш будет отличаться от предыдущего.

Comment: Укажите все таки от каких видов атак вы хотите защитится ? "_представьте сколько будет нужно вариантов перебрать_" - вариантов надо будет перебрать абсолютно столько же, сколько надо было бы перебрать для пароля длиной в ваш хеш. Я даже не буду пытаться подобрать пароль и соль, которые знает пользователь, я буду подбирать хеш который отправляется на сервер